# "No such file or directory" in "create foreign server" in "postgresql" in windows

Tags: postgresql

why i see "No such file or directory" error when i try to "create foreign server" in postgresql in windows?

I execute the below Query

```
create extension postgres_fdw1;
CREATE SERVER remoteserver1 FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (host 'localhost', port '5432',  dbname 'Test');
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR current_user SERVER remoteserver1 OPTIONS (user 'postgres', password '123456');
```

and when I try to execute that, I see the below error message

> ERROR:  could not open extension control file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/share/extension/postgres_fdw1.control": No such file or directory
>   ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: could not open extension control file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/share/extension/postgres_fdw1.control": No such file or directory
>   SQL state: 58P01

I want to have two server like this picture :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnieM.jpg)

Comment: The extension is called `postgres_fdw`, not `postgres_fdw1`

Comment: I do that, there is no error but it has no effect and still I have one server